# Alguien sabe porque uno de los dos Adapters, funciona pero el otro no?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Tengo 2 clases llamadas MyAdapterBig/MyAdapterSmall, representan dos frigos.
El tema es que uno de ellos el small va perfectamente, cuando le doy al boton de delete borra, pero el otro Adapter, no entra en el for... entonces... me estoy volviendo loco.

Alguien puede ver el fallo que yo no consigo ver ??

MyAdapterBig, este no va, no se porque razon nunca entra aqui:

```
for (DataSnapshot prodSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
```

Lo que no se porque...

```
package com.virtualmon.sergisabgg.whateattoday;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyAdapterBig extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterBig.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Productos> frigos;

    public MyAdapterBig(ArrayList<Productos> frigos) {
        this.frigos = frigos;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_big, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Productos object = frigos.get(position);

        String firstText = object.getNombre();

        holder.text1.setText(firstText);

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = holder.text1.getText().toString();
                holder.myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Log.d("SDASDASDASDASDASD ", "" + dataSnapshot.getChildren().toString());
                        for (DataSnapshot prodSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("SDASDASDASDASDASD ", "" + "12312313123123123123");
                            if (prodSnapshot.getValue(Productos.class).getNombre().equals(name)) {
                                Productos prod = prodSnapshot.getValue(Productos.class);
                                prodSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                Log.d("Delete:", prod.toString());
                                frigos.remove(prod);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.w("Error", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return frigos.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        Button delete;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("bigFrigos");

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        }
    }

}
```

En cambio este funciona de maravilla....

```
package com.virtualmon.sergisabgg.whateattoday;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyAdapterSmall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterSmall.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Productos> frigos;

    public MyAdapterSmall(ArrayList<Productos> arrayList) {
        frigos = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Productos object = frigos.get(position);

        String firstText = object.getNombre();

        holder.text1.setText(firstText);

        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name = holder.text1.getText().toString();
                holder.myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot prodSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            if (prodSnapshot.getValue(Productos.class).getNombre().equals(name)) {
                                Productos prod = prodSnapshot.getValue(Productos.class);
                                prodSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                Log.d("Delete:", prod.toString());
                                frigos.remove(prod);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                        // Failed to read value
                        Log.w("Error", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return frigos.size();
    }


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        Button delete;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("smallFrigo");

        MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

        }
    }

}
```

Muchas gracias.
Un cordial saludo.

Comment: Hola Sergio revisaste el LogCat, se muestra algún error?

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por comentar, no no muestra nigun error, esto es lo raro por eso puse esos Log.d, lo unico que aparece cuando clico en le boton es esto :

D/SDASDASDASDASDASD: com.google.firebase.database.zza@eda2c9a

que es el log que puse antes del for....

Comment: Agregué mi respuesta, primero asegura existe la estructura de "smallFrigo"

Comment: te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es importante asegures que existe la referencia "bigFrigos", esta es llamada en el `Adapter` que comentas no funciona:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("bigFrigos");
```

y no necesitas sobreescribir el método:

```
  @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
```